# Submitting a form to an Angular 2 App

Tags: forms, angular

What is the best way to submit a form to an Angular 2 app? I.e. from a non-angular website, to an Angular app?

You cannot simply put the app as the action URL with `method="GET"` as Angular 2 uses "matrix URL notation" and the browser will add the form fields as regular params (?= , &=).

For example this approach does not work, assuming the URL is an Angular 2 app:

```
<form method="GET" action="http://myangular2app.com/search;">
    <input name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

The browser will navigate to a URL like `http://myangular2app.com/search;?q=mysearch` when it needs to be `http://myangular2app.com/search;q=mysearch` (no question mark).

Answer (score 1):

You can utilise two-way binding with use of the `ngModel` directive

```
<input name="q" [(ngModel)]='name'>
```

You will need to import the [forms modules](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) to utilise two-way binding; as well as the Http module for the request:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Http }        from '@angular/http';
```

Use this for the call:

```
this.http.get("http://myangular2app.com/search;q="+mysearch)
```

---

If you are new to Angular2 I would recommend you spend a bit of time looking of the [Angular2 tutorial 'Tour of Heroes'](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/)

This walks you through creating a simple web application involving (among other things) forms, data binding and HTTP requests

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: ok - let me clarify. If you utilise the forms module, you don't need to worry about angulars matrix URL notation